# Retrieve the child terms by having the parent's information

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I have access through a series of joins to the terms table, in order to bring out all the taxonomies that are associated with the post if I wanted to.

with this code:

```
<?php
echo "{$r->term_id}";
echo "{$r->name}";
?>
```

i have:

```
22
Sito Web
```

Sito Web it s a children taxonomy `servizi_pro`

how to retrive only the children about: `Sito Web`

i want only the childern from: `$r->name`

schema:

```
servizi_pro
|
|_ Sito Web
   |
   |_ 1600
```

i want have 1600

update:

if I do this it returns me all those associated with all the posts instead of having a foreach loop I would like it to return me specific for all the posts

```
$terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'servizi_pro', 'parent' => $r->term_id ) );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

if I do so it returns me all those associated with all the posts instead of having a foreach loop I would like it to return to me specific to each post.

Show me the third level of taxonomy associated with each single post for the searched taxonomy "sito-web"

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, check the result of `get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'servizi_pro', 'parent' => $r->term_id ) )`

Comment: @IvanShatsky yes

Comment: @IvanShatsky read my question i have update

Comment: Sorry, still can't understand what exactly your question is. You have some post ID and want to check if this post belongs to any of the taxonomies that are children of `$r->term_id` taxonomy?